# Calculate correlation coefficients and p-values from a hierarchical dataset, using multiple loops

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation, hierarchical-data

I have a data set describing several behavioural variables from individuals that belong to different (1) species, (2) sexes, and (3) reproductive stages. 
My goal is to create a series of loops that would allow me to calculate the Spearman correlation coefficient and p-value between each behavioural variable (e.g. "hiding" below) to another variable of interest ("nesting" below) per species per sex per stage.
What I would like in the end is a data frame that would look like this:

```
Species   Sex   Stage   Spearman_corr_coef   p-value   behaviour
PO        m     virgin  0.78                 0.01      hiding
PO        f     virgin  0.54                 0.09      hiding
PO        m     parent  0.03                 0.71      hiding
PO        f     parent  0.14                 0.59      hiding
BW        m     virgin  0.71                 0.02      hiding
BW        f     virgin  0.79                 0.04      hiding
...       ...   ...     ...                  ...       ...
```

Here is how to create a fake dataset that resembles mine:

```
ID<-as.factor(rep(seq(from=1, to=40), each=2))
hiding <- rnorm(80)
attacking <- rnorm(80)
nesting <- rnorm(80)
sex <- as.factor(rep(c("m","f"),each=2, times=20))
species <- as.factor(rep(c("A", "B"), each=40))
stage<-as.factor(rep(c("virgin", "parent"), times=80))

df <- data.frame(ID, sex, species, stage, nesting, hiding, attacking)
```

I would like to correlate the values for "nesting" (variable of interest) to "hiding" and "attacking", using the Spearman correlation test on a per species per sex per stage basis. I would then like to extract the correlation coefficient and p-value and integrate all of them into a dataframe (like shown above).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something like `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(behaviour, value, hiding, attacking) %>% group_by(sex, species, stage, behaviour) %>% do(cor.test = broom::tidy(cor.test(.$nesting, .$value, method = 'spearman'))) %>% ungroup() %>% unnest()`

Comment: Could you please describe what the elements of your comment do? I am not familiar with this package. Thanks

Comment: `tidyr::gather` reshapes to long form; then `dplyr::group_by` sets grouping for `do`, which creates a list column that is the result of a `cor.test` on the group's data, simplified to a data.frame by `broom::tidy`. `ungroup` and `unnest` remove the grouping and expand it back to an ordinary data.frame. [_R for Data Science_](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) is a good starting point to understand the larger grammar.